# Unable to configure spring cloud config server

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I am implementing one spring cloud application, for which I am configuring config server on windows environment. I am setting up a native filesystem-based config server. I am not using Git, so I have created a local file structure.

Config server **application.properties** file

```
server.port = 8208 

spring.cloud.config.server.native.searchLocations = D:\Repository

spring.profiles.active=native
```

**pom.xml**

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath />
</parent>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Dalston.SR1</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

ConfigServer Class-

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.config.server.EnableConfigServer;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigServer
public class MicroserviceConfigServer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MicroserviceConfigServer.class, args);
    }
}
```

When I run the application, it successfully loaded and run on tomcat server with port 8208. but the problem is with the repository location. I got following response for http://localhost:8208/config/default/master

```
{"name":"config","profiles":["default"],"label":"master","version":null,"state":null,"propertySources":[]}
```

but I have many .properties files in the repository, still those files are not accessible to other services as well. Please help me to resolve this problem.

Comment: There's not enough information to help you. Please provide your full configuration and what version you are using?

Comment: I have been updated some file details, Please let me know any other information required.

Comment: You shouldn't be using `spring-cloud-starter-parent` as a parent. You've also mixed 1.0.0 (from Angel), with Dalston.

Comment: @YogeshKhopade, [check this paragraph](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/multi/multi__spring_cloud_config_server.html#_file_system_backend)

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are using Windows. In that case - try to use home folder of current user, so change `D:\Repository` to something like `~/Repository`. Home folder of your user situated at `c:\Users\<YOUR USER NAME>`

And put your config into this folder

Another approach is to use note on official page of Spring Cloud Config: *"On Windows, you need an extra "/" in the file URL if it is absolute with a drive prefix"*